# How to Move JS from Client to Server in Node/Express?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have a .handlebars file that includes both HTML and JS (below). This is a simple form that the user can expand by clicking a "New Form Field" button. That button simply adds a new text field. The user can create as many form fields as they want before submitting the form.

I was wondering what is the best way to take the Javascript out of the HTML and keep it on the server-side only. Would I put it under a route handler in my app.js file, or would it be in a module that is exported to my app.js file? Or is there something else I should be Googling? Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="newForm">    
   <div id="container">
      <p>Form field 1.)</p>
          <span><p><input type="text" name="question1"><br></p>    
   </div>    
   <button type="button" id="newF">+ New Form Field</button><br><br>    
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>    
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var newFbtn = $("#newF");
var fieldCount = 1;

newFbtn.click(function() {
  fieldCount++;  
  $("#container").append(

      '<p>Form field ' + fieldCount + '.)</p>' +
      '<span><p><input type="text">'
  )

});
```

Link to codepen: http://codepen.io/Jake_Ratliff/pen/KzjaQz

Comment: What are you asking? How to extract it from your html but keep it bundled when served to the browser, or how to extract it and run it from the server side?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I am asking how to keep it bundled. Perhaps it is best to keep in the client, since it is only modifying the DOM (as the user below stated), and putting it on the server could slow it down in client.

Comment: Just find any ol' tutorial on putting together a simple web server with node.js, they should tell you how to specify a folder path that will be exposed to the browser for serving static assets like client-side javascript files, images, css, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think you should move it in the first place?

If your JavaScript is only modifying the DOM (the HTML page), then it does not make sense to put it on the server side. If it were doing complex calculations or retrieving something from a database, then that would make sense, but appending flat HTML should be kept client side.